# Know of any cross platform socket library (windows & Linux) in C?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, cross-platform

I am looking to do socket communications (listen, accept, connect, recv, send, disconnect) in both linux and windows. My project is in C, so unless someone can think of a way for me to integrate C++ libraries into a C project the library will have to be in C as well.

Ultimately, I would like the library to have ipv6 support and non-blocking mode, however, these things are not essential.

Does anyone know of any libraries/cross-platform example code? Even just large code snippets would help. So far the few socket libraries I have found have been in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off-hand, I can think of four libraries:

- [GLib Channels](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-IO-Channels.html) from the [GLib framework](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) can abstract socket usage, but you'll need platform-specific code for socket creation.
- [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) is a platform abstraction layer for node.js and handles, among other things, sockets and async IO.
- The [Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) also contains [network routines](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__network__io.html).
- The [Netscape Portable Runtime](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/) does [socket manipulation](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/priofnc.html#18579) as well.

Comment: Thankyou very much, thats an awesome start. At the moment, im looking at libuv, as it seems to have a good balance between size/simplicity and efficiency. Out of curiosity, what were your search terms that yielded those results? or did you know of them already?

Comment: @64bit_twitchyliquid: I don't remember when I first came across GLib, but in my mind, it occupies the place of a standard lib for C more in tune with what other languages offer; I found APR and NSPR when I looked for a platform-abstraction lib and I know of libuv because it's used by the Rust programming language; actually, all of these except libuv are listed on http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/portability-libs/ , the first result of a google search for *C cross platform abstraction lib*

Answer (score 8):

The [plibsys](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys) library provides all the requested features: cross-platform and portable, lightweight, provides socket IPv4 and IPv6 support as well as many other useful things like multithreading. Works with sockets in non-blocking mode (though you can switch to a blocking one, too). Has quite a good documentation with the test code examples.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know one library that complies both Windows and Linux but I think `winsock` is similar enough to Linux socket programming.

In particular it supplies you 'select()' and the other functions mentioned. I guess you will need a very thin #ifdef wrapper to avoid type casting warnings.

[See here the winsock page for select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

check [HS Sockets C Source Library for Windows and Linux](http://www.hillstone-software.com/hs_sockets_library_details.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Ptlib  provides cross platform C++ code that works well for sockets. www.opalvoip.org

Copes nicely with threads. Some support for mac and BSD. Under active development and maintainance.  MPL 
Core library in Ekiga - the preferred desktop app that does SIP & H.323

For windows - it compiles with MSVC.
for linux, it compiles with gcc autoconf make etc.

OK, it is C++, but you can work with that... 
Have a the source inside ptlib/samples - there are many examples of using ptlib there.

Comment: He was asking specifically for a C library.

Answer (score -3):

[The Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html) includes these features.