# Best Way To Work With FileSystems?

Tags: c, file, filesystems, dirent.h

What's the best way to work with file systems in C?

There is of course **dirent.h** , but from what I've heard it isn't completely guaranteed to be available on all platforms and compilers, for example the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, for one, doesn't support it.

For now, the best thing I've seen is the file handling functions in GLib. Is there any better way?

What I am looking for is a well-designed, preferably cross-platform library / code / something else supported by all main-stream compilers and is well-documented. Any ideas?

Comment: Why C? Could you possibly pick a worse language?

Comment: What specifically do you want to do with file systems?  If you simply want to read/write files, stdio.h will do the job.  But I think you want to do more, such as traverse directories etc.  Is that correct?

Comment: since file system work is inherently system dependent, cross platform libraries will be few and far between

Comment: @DeadMG I'm not going to get into a flame war, but I'd like to hear your explanation of why C is so bad.  After all, your favorite operating system kernel (whether it be Windows, or Mac OS, or Linux) is written mostly in C.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin well, to be specific, I want to open a directory, search all files in it for a '*.lmap' extension, and parse them.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: Horrendously unsafe and insecure? Incredibly slow? No generics? No resource management? No namespaces? No exceptions? Horrific macro abuse? That's just to begin with, *and* that's just the bad things about C that C++ doesn't share, let alone an exhaustive list. Those kernels are written in C because there was nothing else at the time, not because C is a good idea. It isn't. Also, if you don't wish to start a flamewar, come to the C++ chat and I will gladly enumerate for you in *great detail* exactly how C sucks.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) to the above mentioned chat room. FIGHT! FIGHT! FIGHT! :D

Comment: @DeadMG: C is slow? i thought that was the one thing it was good at.

Comment: @Claudiu: Tell that to O(n) string length, for example. Or no inlinable algorithms? There are other examples.

Comment: I second @DeadMG here. C has strengths for *a few* use cases (interop with other languages or embedded programming for instance), but certainly not for manipulating files in a system agnostic way... Did you look into languages like Python (if C is not an absolute requirement) ?

Comment: @DeadMG So much for civility and politeness.

Comment: Thanks all, actually there was a problem with a C Library which had variables with names like `class` which I couldn't use it with C++. But now its solved with the help of @DeadMG. Now I finally can use something better than C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201602/48015) about cross-platform socket libraries, but it's equally good for your question:

- [GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) comes with [file utilities](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-File-Utilities.html)
- [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) provides [file system methods](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/include/uv.h#L1165)
- [APR](http://apr.apache.org/) has [directory manipulation functions](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__dir.html)
- [NSPR](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/) exposes [directory i/o functions](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/priofnc.html#18353)